# Image not displaying on github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I am building a portfolio blog on github I created a folder name img with the image mobil.PNG this image load and display with github when viewing the portfolio on github but does not show on the actual site, it shows a broken file link.
This is the path to the file https://github.com/desmond75/desmond75.github.io/blob/master/img/mobil.PNG
This img folder is at the root level of the directory this is how I am referencing the file

```
![Here is the alt text](https://github.com/desmond75/desmond75.github.io/blob/master/img/mobil.PNG "Here is the Title text")
```

[tutorial](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "copy path" button on that page will give you the correct path to a usable image: https://desmond75.github.io/img/mobil.PNG

So, in markdown:

```
![Here is the alt text](https://desmond75.github.io/img/mobil.PNG "Here is the Title text")
```

And the rendered output, with the alt-text:

[image: Here is the alt text]

Comment: Thank you so much Mureinik  i have been on this for 2 days now

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only for images within GitHub domains. It doesn’t work for external domains